# smtplib doesn't send an email | Python

Tags: python, smtplib

Not getting errors but it's not sending an email to the receivers email neither.

Using an email I got from namecheap (they use privateemail).

````
async def contents(self, email): 
    email = email.strip()
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message["From"] = "config@hvh.monster"
    message["To"] = email
    message["Subject"] ="SCARY HVH CONFIGURATION"
    message["Bcc"] = email
    message.attach(MIMEText(open("scarychina.txt", "r+").read(), "plain"))
    with open("js.zip", 'rb') as attachment:
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header("Content-Disposition", f"attachment; filename= js.zip",)
    message.attach(part)
    return str(message)

async def send_config(self, email: str):
    try:
        contents = await self.contents(email)
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mail.privateemail.com", 465, ssl.create_default_context())
        server.login("config@hvh.monster", email_pass)
        server.sendmail("config@hvh.monster", email, contents)
        print("Sent an email to " + email)
        server.quit() 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)```
````

Comment: Have you tried sending simpler messages, or sending to different email addresses?  If you are only trying this complex case directed at a single test email account, you've got a lot of potential places things could be going wrong.  I would suggest that you start with a simple message.  If that works, then you know it has to do with the contents of the message or how you are putting it together.  If that doesn't work either, then you can explore if the problem has to do with the particular address you are sending to.

Comment: Another thing you can try is providing a bad password, or doing other things that should cause a failure.  If they don't, then you might be doing something wrong that should cause an error, but isn't doing so, like supplying the wrong password.  - Divide and conquer.  Start simple.  Explore what happens when you change various things.

Comment: Check the return value of `server.sendmail` - if it's empty then the message is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My email is feasible, the code is as follows

```py
import smtplib 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formataddr


class SendMail(object):
    def __init__(self, mail_title, mail_contain):
        self.sender='sender email'
        self.accepter='accepter email'
        self.mail_title = mail_title
        self.mail_contain = mail_contain

    def send_data(self):
        try:
            msg = MIMEText(self.mail_contain, 'html', 'utf-8')
            msg['From'] = formataddr(["sender name", self.sender])
            msg['To'] = ";".join(self.accepter)
            msg['Subject'] = self.mail_title
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp host",465)
            server.login(self.sender, "password")
            server.sendmail(self.sender, self.accepter, msg.as_string())
            server.quit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e, 'send fail....')
```